# Observing commands in another ViewModel

Tags: xamarin.forms, reactiveui

I'm not sure how to title this question since I'm not sure what is wrong, but I'm having trouble with observing to commands in another viewmodel.

I have a BoxPageViewModel that contains a `SourceCache<BoxViewModel>` 'Boxes' and a `SourceCache<ItemViewModel>` 'Items'. 
I want functionality to add an ItemViewModel to a BoxViewModel, and it should then be removed from 'Items'.

My plan is to have a Add-command in the BoxViewModel that adds an Item to a SourceList in the BoxViewModel. The BoxPageViewModel "listens" for when any of its boxes call 'Add' and then removes the newest item of that box from 'Items'

I've looked at the [documentation for the Message Bus](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/message-bus/) to learn how to observe when a command in another viewmodel is called. I've kind of gotten it to work, but not quite.

My problem is that the code for removing the item from the ItemsSource is only called before the ObservableAsPropertyHelper 'IsFull' in the BoxViewModel is set for the first time, and I have no idea why.
As of now, 'IsFull' should be true if the Box contains 2 or more items. When I add the first Item to the Box, its removed from Items in the BoxPageViewModel. But when I add the second item, the code for removing the item from Items is never called.

If I remove 'IsFull' it works fine, but I really need a way to tell when all the boxes are 'full' or 'finished' in some way.

I've tried to use `.ToObservableChangeSet().AutoRefreshOnObservable(x => x.Add)` instead of 
`.ToObservableChangeSet().AutoRefresh()` but it makes no difference. I'm kinda at a loss here since I'm not quite sure how this works. I would really like to get an explanation for why the code behaves as it does.

Bonus question: I also can't seem to get the 'Done' property of the BoxPageViewModel to true, Even though I have checked in a test-method that `_boxes.Select(b => b.All(x => x.IsFull))` is true. Is there something wrong with how I have defined this property?

```cs
public class BoxViewModel : ReactiveObject
    {
        readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<bool> isFull;
        public bool IsFull => isFull.Value;

        public SourceList<Item> Items = new SourceList<Item>();

        public ReactiveCommand<int, Unit> Add { get; }

        public BoxViewModel()
        {
            Add = ReactiveCommand.Create<int>(AddToBox);

            Items.Connect()
                .ToCollection()
                .Select(c => c.Count >= 2)
                .ToProperty(this, x => x.IsFull, out isFull);
        }

        private void AddToBox(int id)
        {
            // Adding a new item while testing.
            Items.Add(new Item { Id = id });
        }
    }
```

In the BoxPageViewModel I try to observe when the AddToBox command is called and then remove the item from its Items SourceCache.

```cs
public class BoxPageViewModel : ReactiveObject, IRoutableViewModel
    {
        private SourceCache<Item, int> ItemsSource = new SourceCache<Item, int>(x => x.Id);

        private SourceCache<BoxViewModel, int> BoxSource = new SourceCache<BoxViewModel, int>(x => x.Id);
        private ReadOnlyObservableCollection<BoxViewModel> _boxes;
        public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<BoxViewModel> Boxes => _boxes;

        private ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Item> _items;
        public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Item> Items => _items;

        readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<bool> done;
        public bool Done => done.Value;

        public BoxPageViewModel()
        {
            var box1 = new BoxViewModel { Id = 1 };
            var box2 = new BoxViewModel { Id = 2 };

            BoxSource.AddOrUpdate(box1);
            BoxSource.AddOrUpdate(box2);

            // I have left out the part where my items are created
            ItemsSource.AddOrUpdate(items);

            ItemsSource.Connect()
                .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
                .Bind(out _items)
                .Subscribe();

            BoxSource.Connect()
                .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
                .Bind(out _boxes)
                .Subscribe();

            _boxes.ToObservableChangeSet()
                .ToCollection()
                .Select(b => b.All(x => x.IsFull))
                .ToProperty(this, x => x.Done, out done);

            _boxes
                .ToObservableChangeSet()
                .AutoRefresh()
                .Select(_ => WhenAnyBoxAdded())
                .Switch()   
                .Subscribe(box =>
                {
                    var latestItem = box.Items.Items.Last();
                    ItemsSource.Remove(latestItem.Id);
                });
        }

        IObservable<BoxViewModel> WhenAnyBoxAdded()
        {
            return _boxes
                .Select(x => x.Add.Select(_ => x))
                .Merge();
        }
}
```

Comment: I never used this package that you mean, I usually use the MessageCenter. it isn't an answer, but I hope be useful to you. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center

Comment: Yeah i've been considering just using the message center instead or the ReactiveUI version of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you chose to use MessageCenter.
The Xamarin.Forms MessagingCenter class implements the publish-subscribe pattern, allowing message-based communication between components that are inconvenient to link by object and type references. This mechanism allows publishers and subscribers to communicate without having a reference to each other, helping to reduce dependencies between them.

First, signing (this code must be executed before):

> 

```
Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object>(this, "key", async message =>
{                
   //your code here.
});
```

And sending a message:

> 

```
Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.Send<object>(new object(), "key");
```

Comment: Let me know if this help you.